# Code working fine with Highchart but not with Highstock

Tags: highcharts

Recently I switched from highchart to highstock, but some of the features are not working fine for me.

When I hide a series and then show it again, then some problem accures, and which doesnt redraw the chart properly.

Trying to explain by screenshots:

1. When series is **On** 
   [image]
2. When series is **Off**
   [image]
3. After Turning **On** again, highchart results same as image 1, but highstock results as following:
   [image]

**And it gives error:**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'complete' of undefined    **highstock.js:35**

Comment: Are you using plotLines or plotBands? It's broken in 3.0.9. Try to use master: `http://github.highcharts.com/master/highstock.js`. If not, then recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I am using plotLines and PlotBand. Master js solved not only this issue, but some others as well :)